# How to deny write premissions to a user for all tables except one

Tags: sql-server

We have some 50 tables, and we need to deny write permissions to every table except for one table for particular user.

How can we do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try doing exactly what you describe, deny write to 49 tables and grant to 1?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it with dynamic SQL. The Print may not show you the whole command because of output limitations in Management Studio. You'll need to update the username and exception.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + '
    DENY UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON ' + 
    QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id])) + '.'
    + QUOTENAME(name) + ' TO [username];' -- fix this username
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name <> 'exception'; -- fix this to be the one you want to allow

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio:

Go to the properties page for the user, then the User Mapping tab.

Tick public and db_datareader (do not tick db_denydatawriter) for the appropriate database.

This will only grant them read access.

Then you can grant insert and update for the user to the table using a query similar to this:

```
GRANT INSERT ON OBJECT::dbo.MyTable TO Fred
GRANT UPDATE ON OBJECT::dbo.MyTable TO Fred
```